# Conditionally create new records for many to many relationship in activerecords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm working on `RoR` project with `ActiveRecord` and I'm pretty new to these technologies.

I have two models:

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
...
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
...
```

**Role.rb**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
...
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
...
```

So now I'm creating a new role:

```
Role.where(name: 'my_new_role').first_or_create!
```

and I want to create a rake task which will add this role for users who already have `admin` role and to all other users who are NOT with `unfit_role` role.

If I was doing this with pure `SQL` I would most likely preform a select to collect all user id's which I want to update and then execute another update query for all id's that I've collected.

However I feel that `ActiveRecord` have some specifics which I can't quite understand yet but I've decided to try some other approach.

Currently I have this code:

```
new_role = Role.where(name: :my_new_role).first

User.all.each do |entity|
  entity.roles << new_role if entity.has_role?('admin')
  entity.roles << new_role if !entity.has_role?('unfit_role')
end
```

And `has_role` is simple helper method which selects all roles once and the check with `include?` if a given role is in the selected list with roles.

Based on 1-2 trial runs, it seems that actually this is working but I really don't like the implementation. Mostly the way I check if a certain user (entity) has a given role. I feel that this is pretty inefficient way to perform a relatively easy task, so I wonder how can implement this in a different way so it's quicker.

Comment: What is the database you are using?

Comment: PostgreSQL it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Postgres [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-aggregate.html) to make the query more efficient:

```
new_role = Role.where(name: 'my_new_role').first!
admin_role = Role.where(name: 'admin').first!
unfit_role = Role.where(name: 'unfit_role').first!

User.joins(:roles).group(:id).having("bool_or(roles.id = #{admin_role.id}) or not bool_or(roles.id = #{unfit_role.id})").each do |entity|
  entity.roles << new_role
end
```